# Ports is not working

Tags: 20.04, apache2, virtualmin

i installed ubuntu in VMware EXsi 5.5.0 installed webmin and virtualmin, i enabled the ufw, set ports ,installed apache, but with write ip and then port after it,  its not opening, i have checked each and everything

Comment: If you have checked "everything", please provide some proof. Logs, command outputs etc. People will then be able to assess if you maybe missed something in "everything".